# Load json files with different schema for a same element in Pig

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to load json files, and when I load a specific field, pig seems to recognize it for a string or a bag.

The Json element "program" in the file can be:

```
"program":"open"
```

Or :

```
"program": ["jump","jump"]
```

I'm using the following code to load the file :

```
rel = LOAD '$filePath' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS (json:map []);

flat = FOREACH rel GENERATE
(chararray)json#'program' AS program;
```

But when I'm trying to filter, the script got an error (cannot filter with a bag).

```
open = FILTER flat BY program MATCHES 'open';
```

If anyone got an idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If anyone has the same problem, I solved with this : FLATTEN( json#'program') AS program

Comment: Feel free to answer below rather than leave a comment